# Replace keys with values (but don't flip)

Tags: php, arrays, function

I have an array like this:

```
["AF"]=> string(11) "Afghanistan" 
["002"]=> string(6) "Africa" 
["AL"]=> string(7) "Albania"
 ...
```

Now I would like to have an array like this:

```
["Afghanistan"]=> string(11) "Afghanistan" 
["Africa"]=> string(6) "Africa" 
["Albania"]=> string(7) "Albania"
 ...
```

Is this possible without looping through them? (Is there a php function for this?) When I searched Google I found arary_flip but that's switching the keys and values...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`array_combine()`](http://php.net/array_combine):

```
$result = array_combine($array, $array);
```

Or for better readability:

```
$keys = $values = array_values($arr);
$result = array_combine($keys, $values);
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/123733)

Answer (score 5):

I think [`array_combine()`](http://php.net/array-combine) is what you need

```
$a = array_combine($a, $a);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$names = array("AF"=>"Afghanistan" ,"002"=>"Africa" ,"AL"=>"Albania");
$names = array_combine($names, $names);
print_r($names);
```